# Voting to re-open a closed question from the flags page (moderator view) shows the question as "closed" (twice)

Tags: bug, flags, reopened-questions

On *Drupal Answers* I voted to re-open [a question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65129/list-of-cities-and-international-airports) after the OP edited it, and flagged it for moderation attention. Since I am a moderator there, the question was immediately re-opened, but it was shown as in the following screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

[I closed the question again](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/65129/revisions) to see if it was a temporary glitch, but I got the same result, when I reopened it.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I expect it was the OP that flagged it for moderator attention, which is why kiamlaluno was looking at it.

Comment: which specific page were you in for this? the question page? or?

Comment: @MarcGravell I see this from the page listing all the flags: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/admin/dashboard.